# Are questions about puzzle video games on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can I ask questions about how to solve the puzzles in puzzle video games? For example, could I ask questions about techniques for playing the game [Antichamber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichamber) or how to solve some of its specific puzzles?

(I don't currently have any specific questions I want to ask, but I'm wondering whether these questions are in the site's scope.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite honestly, I don't see why not. It seems to be a logical extension of our site scope. Antichamber is definitely a puzzle game, and puzzles are on-topic here, so questions about puzzles in games by extension reasonably should be.

Of course, we don't really have precedent for puzzle video games (yet!), so the only thing I can *definitively* say is: try it, and let's see how it goes!

Comment: We do have a well-received precedent, albeit a weak one (it's a quite simple game): [2048](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2048).

Comment: And another (as you surely know): http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/how-do-i-solve-the-between-worlds-android-puzzle-game